# JavaScript SlideShow that will work in Ebay listings?

Tags: javascript, scripting, ebay-design-templates

I am after jscript SlideShow, not based on JQuery etc. as I am pretty sure you can't reference external
javascript library in Ebay listings?

Ideally not just switching images, but one for layers. That will slide a bunch of divs or html data, where I can put images and text etc. Also having it work in IE6 and failing gracefully for anyone with js off would be a plus.

This one here is what I am after, does not use any library
but unfortunately still does not work in Ebay.[Tiny SlideShow](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-slideshow/)

Thanks..

Comment: Is this what you had in mind? Basic degradation, smooth scrolling that stops when you are over it, and best of all no library required. http://jsfiddle.net/xQEPQ/3/ EDIT: I have no idea if it works in IE6, I have no way to test that.

Comment: More something like this: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/javascript-slideshow/

Comment: that doesn't use jQuery or any other library...why not just use that code?

Answer (score 1):

If javascript is allowed on the page, you could include the slide-show images on the page, something like this:

```
<img src="slide1" onclick="showslide(2)">
<img src="slide2" onclick="showslide(3)">
<img src="slide3" onclick="showslide(1)">
```

Then include a simple script to change the picture, for example:

```
<script>
function showslide(number) {
    document.getElementById("slide1").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("slide2").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("slide3").style.display="none"
    document.getElementById("slide"+number).style.display="block"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not allowed in eBay item description. But you can use an official eBay application such as [Flash Gallery](http://apps.ebay.com/selling?ViewEAppDetails&stab=1&mId=745&appType=1&appId=FlashGallery.3dsellers.com). It will create a Flash gallery and insert it into your listing. You can also use other Flash galleries that do not require JavaScript.